# Can't change screen brightness inside Linux on Acer

Tags: linux, brightness, acer-travelmate

Acer TravelMate 4740 series laptop.

Brightness control keys (Fn+Right/Left) work on Windows 7, but not on Linux(tried both Ubuntu and Kubuntu).

Linux shows the brightness bar(bulb) when the keys are pressed, it even increases and decreases, but the brightness does not change.

Volume keys (Fn+Up/Down arrow) work perfectly in all OSs.

Any solution? I guess this is a hardware problem with Acer.

Comment: I'm on a Acer 5745G and the brightness control has always worked, through several revisions of Ubuntu, so I can exclude that it is a general Acer/Linux problem.

Comment: OK. Any scope for a solution?

Comment: I had the same problem once and I fixed it as I've explained at http://joseblog.netau.net/tips-and-tricks/acer-adjust-brightness-problems.php

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
acpi_backlight=vendor
```

to your kernel parameters in the `grub2.cfg` file.

Comment: It helps me with Ubuntu 12.04 on Acer Aspire One D270.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
Option “RegistryDwords” “EnableBrightnessControl=1″
```

To the `"Device"` section in your `xorg.conf`.

I had a very similar problem on my Lenovo W510 with Ubuntu lucid and it was solved after setting this and logging out and in again.

Edit:
My laptop is not near me, but searching for a sample `xorg.conf` on the net I found many "almost duplicate" posts. Here is a sample on a one of them at askubuntu.com https://askubuntu.com/questions/83965/ubuntu-10-04-cant-adjust-brightness-on-my-lenovo-thinkpad

Comment: Here its /etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe. Why is this? Please give an example of the contents of that file after adding this entry.

Comment: @max I've edited the post and added a link. AFAIK xorg.conf is not a must on Ubuntu any more. Although it was there on my laptop.

Comment: @max Also, if this solution do solve your problem, to my opinion, the question should be marked a duplicate.

Comment: I did that and its causing extreme flickering of the screen! And when I press the brightness keys, flickers even more with black bars.

Comment: Seems that this is not the solution for you, I guess our problems are different. How did you create the xorg.conf to add the option to? Did you copy from your xorg.conf.failsafe? The other options in the sample may not fit your configuration.

Comment: There was no xorg.conf. So I just added that line to xorg.conf.failsafe, copied it in the same directory and renamed it as xorg.conf